# Autolayout : Need constraints for y position or height

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I am trying to satisfying the constraint form a long time but getting above error i.e. is "**Need constraints for y position or height**" for Yellow View and Green View. Basically I have 2 UILabel (dynamic height) within UIView and UIImageView of 4:3 ratio within a Cell.

[image]

And my applied constraint is

[image]

I am also including sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Kxq80hhQyC7Tues4EOJtmmmSCQ4kI-Sn/view?usp=sharing) with above issue.

Answer (score 1):

Just one Constraints required

[image]

Provide SubHeading label `height` >= (`Greater than equal to` ) Constraints

Because of you have applied aspect ratio of `UIImageView`  of 4:3
so it required to fixed other items height and Y position before it apply a ratio to it.
By giving height to subheading Autolayout is able to calculate approx value min required in image ratio

Hope it is helpful to you

Comment: @Prasant Tukadiaya Thanks for your attention but in my case subheading height could be zero also if there is no subheading.

Comment: Greater than equal was the only thing I was missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am attaching two images, one is output and another one is the constraints of views (UILabel, UIImageView). For testing purpose, I put long texts in UILabel, after testing I reduced the text to 'Heading it is' and 'Sub heading it is'. Let me know, if its working of not.enter image description here

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks for your time. Above thing is also working for me, but I put above thing in a View or UITableviewcell, they height is not automatically calculated.

Comment: If you follow the procedure which I shared, the height will be automatically calculated. No matter ‘Heading:’ is there or not.

Comment: Have u applied the ratio also in imageView (for ex. take 4:3)

Comment: If your image is of 4:3 then, setting the image as Espect fit will do the work. And top, bottom, leading, trailing all will be + 5. Thats all.